# How do you know how large or small your cut pieces should be?

Tags: cutting

I was making a curry and I'm having a hard time deciding how large or small I should cut my ingredients. Advice?

Particularly I'm looking for how the taste is effected depending on how large or small your cut pieces are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conventional wisdom suggests cutting ingredients so that it results in bite size pieces so that it is easier to eat, either with spoons, forks or chopsticks.

Vegetables usually do not shrink that much, but meat and fish/seafood will shrink a little bit.

I'd say cut raw meat in to 2 cm pieces.